# Java array I need your thought

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings.

```
For (String [] x = {"serm", "aa", "sazi", "vcd", "aba","kart"};)
```

output will be

```
{"serm", "sazi" , "kart"}.
```

The following code is wrong, What can I do to fix it.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tester all = new Tester();
        String [] x = {"serm", "aa", "sazi", "vcd", "aba","kart"};
        String [] y = all.allLongestStrings(x);
        System.out.println(y);


    }

    String[] allLongestStrings(String[] input) {

        ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(input[0]));
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i].length() == answer.get(0).length()) {
                answer.add(input[i]);
            }
            if (input[i].length() > answer.get(0).length()) {
                answer.add(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return answer.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title is currently useless. Please change it to reflect the issue.

Comment: _The following code is wrong_ tells us precisely nothing. Tell us what you intend the code to do, why you think it should do that, and what it actually does.

Comment: HINT: Try having two methods. One that finds the length of the longest string in your array and another one that gathers all strings that have a certain length into a collection (such as an ArrayList or something - then you can convert this list back to an array)

Comment: The new title is worse than the previous one...

Comment: Ok, you need to get back all longest string, right? But who are longest strings? What actually are you doing at you allLongestStrings() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you solution, but as it homework, it will be only sudo code
problem with your solution is, you are not finging longest strings, but strings same size or bigger than size of first element

```
let helper = []
let maxLength = 0;
for each string in array
if (len(string) >maxLength){
     maxLength = len(string);
     clear(helper)
}
if (len(string) == maxLength)
      helper.add(string)
}
return helper;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
private static String[] solution(String[] inputArray) {

    int longestStrSize = 0;
    List<String> longestStringList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] != null) {
            if (longestStrSize <= inputArray[i].length()) {
                longestStrSize = inputArray[i].length();
                longestStringList.add(inputArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    final int i = longestStrSize;

    return longestStringList.stream().filter(x -> x.length() >= i).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```